# Blurry image after canvas rotate, only in Android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, java-canvas

I've got a custom view with the following code:

```
private final Drawable outerGauge;
private final Drawable innerGauge;
private float rotateX;
private float rotateY;
private int rotation = 0;

{
    outerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_outer);
    innerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_inner);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    outerGauge.draw(canvas);
    canvas.rotate(rotation, rotateX, rotateY);
    innerGauge.draw(canvas);
    canvas.rotate(-rotation, rotateX, rotateY);
}
```

Most of the time this produces perfectly clear images. However, sometimes the result looks like this:
[image: Not really that clear]
This only seems to happen on one of my two test devices. The device is a Motorola moto G, with the Android 6 upgrade. The other test device, which always seems to produce perfectly clear images, is an Oneplus X, Android 5. It's also not consistent, it happens sometimes, and then doesn't again the next moment. From what I've been able to test, it does not even depend on the amount of rotation applied. I've never seen it happen on straight angles though, (0, 90, 180 degrees,) and it does seem to be worse at angles closer to 45 or 135 degrees.

The image in question is an imported SVG, placed directly in the res/drawable folder. Therefore it can't be the resolution. (Also, gauge_outer is placed in exactly the same folder and made exactly the same way, though this one does not become blurry.)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

---

Edit:

Okay, never mind what I said about the complete inconsistency. It appears to be fully consistent, and be worst when the rotation comes closer and closer to 90 degrees. Also, as soon as the rotation is exactly 90 degrees, the indicator completely disappears.

---

Edit:

Behold: two emulators, one running Android 5 and one running Android 6:

[image: Android 5][image: Android 6]

The full source code is as follows:

```
package nl.dvandenberg.gauge;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class GaugeView extends View {
    private static final int ORIGINAL_ROTATE_Y = 510;
    private static final int ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 613;
    private static final int ORIGINAL_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1046;
    private final Drawable outerGauge;
    private final Drawable innerGauge;
    private float rotateX;
    private float rotateY;
    private int rotation = 0;

    {
        outerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_outer);
        innerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_inner);
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setProgress(48);
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setProgress(48);
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setProgress(48);
    }

    public void setProgress(double percentage) {
        this.rotation = (int) (180 * Math.min(100, Math.max(0, percentage)) / 100);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        double width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        double idealHeight = ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT * width / ORIGINAL_IMAGE_WIDTH;
        double height = Math.min(idealHeight, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
        width = width * height / idealHeight;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) height, MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec));

        rotateX = (float) (width / 2f);
        rotateY = (float) (height / ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT * ORIGINAL_ROTATE_Y);

        outerGauge.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
        innerGauge.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        outerGauge.draw(canvas);
        canvas.rotate(rotation, rotateX, rotateY);
        innerGauge.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

with drawable/gauge_inner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1046dp"
    android:height="613dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1046"
    android:viewportHeight="613">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#aa3939"
        android:pathData="M142.541,516.071 C145.053,517.623,156.088,519.334,183.255,522.586
C203.832,525.024,251.438,530.676,289.03,535.184
C326.708,539.641,359.782,543.523,362.537,543.896
C365.292,544.268,388.127,547.018,413.445,550.067 L459.289,555.468
L462.946,560.401 C468.075,567.485,479.691,577.405,489.255,582.968
C499.701,589.062,520.069,594.737,531.817,594.883
C571.623,595.225,607.57,570.083,620.01,533.226
C624.956,518.592,626.123,507.412,624.269,492.201
C622.686,479.259,620.262,472.461,612.212,458.518
C602.012,440.852,592.681,431.69,575.424,422.602
C537.988,402.763,489.163,413.401,462.78,447.108 L458.957,452.086
L449.523,453.146 C444.316,453.727,420.115,456.614,395.829,459.552
C371.456,462.538,346.451,465.429,340.177,466.165
C333.904,466.9,293.067,471.772,249.427,476.991
C205.788,482.211,164.951,487.082,158.678,487.817
C144.122,489.408,139.036,491.998,136.796,498.719
C134.433,505.626,136.72,512.388,142.541,516.07 Z" />
</vector>
```

and drawable/gauge_outer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1046dp"
    android:height="613dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1046"
    android:viewportHeight="613">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#aa3939"
        android:pathData="M488.981,0.56719 C465.882,2.06727,430.783,6.96753,412.984,11.0677
C392.285,15.768,387.285,17.0681,375.285,20.6683
C231.691,63.4706,113.696,164.376,49.898,299.183
C16.6993,369.187,0,444.491,0,523.495
C0,540.296,0.0999961,541.696,1.99992,543.596
C3.99984,545.596,5.29979,545.596,59.4977,545.596
C113.696,545.596,114.996,545.596,116.995,543.596
C118.895,541.696,118.995,540.296,118.995,522.595
C118.995,504.894,118.895,503.494,116.995,501.594
C115.095,499.694,113.695,499.594,85.2962,499.594 L55.6974,499.594
L56.2974,489.793 C60.0973,433.69,76.3966,372.387,101.396,320.384
C103.996,314.984,106.496,310.383,106.896,310.183
C107.396,309.883,110.796,311.483,114.596,313.683
C118.396,315.983,124.396,319.483,127.995,321.583
C131.595,323.583,139.195,328.083,144.994,331.484
C155.694,337.684,159.993,338.884,163.193,336.284
C164.893,334.984,171.293,324.483,177.992,312.083
C183.292,302.282,183.092,299.882,176.492,295.782
C173.992,294.282,162.593,287.582,151.093,281.081 L130.294,269.08 L135.294,261.58
C166.593,214.877,210.691,170.375,258.589,137.273
C268.189,130.673,269.889,129.873,270.489,131.273
C272.389,136.273,298.388,179.776,299.988,180.576
C300.988,181.176,302.788,181.576,303.888,181.576
C306.288,181.576,334.787,165.275,336.787,162.775
C339.187,159.575,337.987,155.575,330.887,143.274
C326.987,136.574,322.987,129.773,322.087,128.273
C321.187,126.673,318.087,121.273,315.287,116.372
C312.387,111.372,309.987,107.072,309.987,106.671
C309.987,105.371,342.586,90.7702,360.385,84.0698
C388.684,73.5692,427.382,63.5687,455.981,59.6685
C468.68,57.8684,490.98,55.5683,495.579,55.5683 L499.979,55.5683 L499.979,85.0699
C499.979,113.271,500.079,114.671,501.979,116.572
C503.879,118.472,505.279,118.572,522.978,118.572
C540.677,118.572,542.077,118.472,543.977,116.572
C545.877,114.672,545.977,113.272,545.977,84.8703 L545.977,55.2687
L555.977,55.9687 C581.776,57.5688,617.875,63.7691,644.874,71.0695
C670.273,77.9699,702.072,89.7705,722.771,99.871
C729.071,102.971,734.671,105.671,735.271,105.871
C735.871,106.071,730.171,117.072,722.172,131.072
C713.772,145.773,707.973,156.973,707.973,158.573
C707.973,162.273,709.373,163.573,718.973,169.274
C741.272,182.375,743.072,183.075,746.772,179.775
C748.472,178.375,765.571,149.773,773.871,134.373 L776.471,129.773
L787.471,137.373 C834.969,170.075,877.067,212.377,910.266,260.98
C912.866,264.78,914.866,268.28,914.766,268.78
C914.566,269.28,903.866,275.78,890.967,283.181
C878.068,290.581,866.668,297.582,865.768,298.782
C862.268,302.782,863.268,305.182,878.268,330.084
C884.168,339.785,886.468,339.885,900.967,331.484
C906.767,328.084,914.366,323.584,917.966,321.583
C921.566,319.483,927.566,315.983,931.365,313.683
C935.265,311.383,938.565,309.583,938.865,309.583
C939.565,309.583,946.665,324.184,952.164,337.084
C972.463,383.986,986.363,440.49,989.663,489.792 L990.263,499.592
L960.664,499.592 C932.265,499.592,930.865,499.692,928.965,501.592
C927.065,503.492,926.965,504.892,926.965,522.593
C926.965,540.294,927.065,541.694,928.965,543.594
C930.965,545.594,932.265,545.594,986.463,545.594
C1041.86,545.594,1041.96,545.594,1044.06,543.494
C1046.26,541.294,1046.26,540.994,1045.66,513.192
C1044.76,470.69,1040.36,436.088,1031.36,398.586
C1027.46,382.685,1026.86,380.485,1020.26,360.084
C1009.06,325.382,990.461,284.58,971.762,253.578
C923.864,174.276,855.866,108.873,775.07,64.3706
C712.572,29.8688,645.075,8.96764,574.477,2.06727
C555.278,0.16716,507.68,-0.63288,488.981,0.56719 Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Where do the images sit in the resource folders?

Comment: Is it really caused by the `canvas.rotate`? If you remove those `.rotate` lines, does it look ok again?

Comment: @weston I updated my question, unfortunately removing .rotate is not really a viable testing strategy due to the inconsistent nature of the problem. It does seem like a rotation by 0 degrees never causes any problems though, which is effectively the same. So as to answer your question, I don't think canvas.rotate is the cause, but is a factor.

Comment: OK then, move the `outerGauge.draw(canvas);` to after the rotate. Interested in if they both go blurry together?

Comment: @weston Negative, it does not. It produces exactly the same image.

Comment: exactly the same? But with the outer image rotated also yes?

Comment: @weston Oh, you mean like that. I thought you meant outside of the "rotate block", lemme check....
They indeed both become blurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not an answer, I have managed to find a workaround. This workaround relies on drawing the image onto a canvas, which is linked to a bitmap, which is then drawn onto the final, rotated canvas in the onDraw method.

It seems like this problem really only arises with nodpi-drawables, in other words, imported svg's. It is however, very consistent. Whether the shape is a multi-path vector or a simple square does not matter, the problem will always take exactly the same shape, with images disappearing entirely when the canvas is rotated 90°.

The full code I used to bypass this problem is as follows:

```
package nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor.customViews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor.R;

public class GaugeView extends View {
    private static final int ORIGINAL_ROTATE_Y = 510;
    private static final int ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 613;
    private static final int ORIGINAL_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1046;
    private final Drawable outerGauge, innerGauge;
    private float rotateX;
    private float rotateY;
    private int rotation = 0;

    private Bitmap innerGaugeBitmap;

    private final Canvas innerGaugeCanvas;

    {
        outerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_outer);
        innerGauge = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.gauge_inner);
        innerGaugeCanvas = new Canvas();
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GaugeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setProgress(double percentage) {
        this.rotation = (int) (180 * Math.min(100, Math.max(0, percentage)) / 100);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        double width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        double idealHeight = ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT * width / ORIGINAL_IMAGE_WIDTH;
        double height = Math.min(idealHeight, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
        width = width * height / idealHeight;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) height, MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec));

        rotateX = (float) (width / 2f);
        rotateY = (float) (height / ORIGINAL_IMAGE_HEIGHT * ORIGINAL_ROTATE_Y);

        outerGauge.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
        innerGauge.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);

        if (innerGaugeBitmap != null){
            innerGaugeBitmap.recycle();
        }
        innerGaugeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Gives LINT-warning draw-allocation, but no other way to upscale bitmaps exists.
        innerGaugeCanvas.setBitmap(innerGaugeBitmap);
        innerGaugeBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        innerGauge.draw(innerGaugeCanvas);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        outerGauge.draw(canvas);
        canvas.rotate(rotation, rotateX, rotateY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(innerGaugeBitmap,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

with the important part occuring in the onMeasure method:

```
        if (innerGaugeBitmap != null){
            innerGaugeBitmap.recycle();
        }
        innerGaugeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Gives LINT-warning draw-allocation, but no other way to upscale bitmaps exists.
        innerGaugeCanvas.setBitmap(innerGaugeBitmap);
        innerGaugeBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        innerGauge.draw(innerGaugeCanvas);
```

I have filed a bugreport at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208453

Comment: thanks, mentioning that svg rotation causing troubles was really helpful