# Memory hog on custom view draw Android

Tags: android, canvas, memory

I've got a question regarding the following memory allocation trace:
[image: Huge memory hog on draw]
As you can see there is a huge memory hog in the draw method of my custom "GaugeView" view. This draw method, however, consists merely of this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    outerGauge.draw(canvas);
    canvas.rotate(rotation, rotateX, rotateY);
    canvas.drawBitmap(innerGaugeBitmap,0,0,null);
}
```

Because of the problem posed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868790/blurry-image-after-canvas-rotate-only-in-android-6) it is not easy to rotate the image ahead of time without quality loss. My questions are as follows:

1. Is my suspicion right, and is this memory hog caused by the canvas.rotate?
2. How could I rid myself of this problem?

Comment: The Android Developer reference recommends that a vector image be limited to a maximum of 200 x 200 dpi, as the initial loading of a vector graphic can be relatively expensive, leading to long draw times. Taken from [here](http://thenewstack.io/vector-images-come-android-devs-need-know/)  also, since the outer part and circle in the middle does not need rotation(I guess), you could make a 9-Patch or PNG of it,and draw only indicator spike with VectorDrawable.

Comment: @Harshiv the indicator is drawn to a bitmap elsewhere, and is therefore not a vector image. The problem could indeed lay in the 'outerGauge' being a vector, I will try drawing that one to a bitmap sooner on too, to see if that improves performance.